# Celery + Django - memory quota exceeded + decrease mem size

Tags: django, heroku, celery

We have an app running on heroku, and are constantly running into mem quota exceeded errors. We've found if we leave it alone, they eventually go away, as the memory is freed. However, we think there are (at least) two possible solutions to decrease these errors, but are having problems finding any information on implementing either.

Our ideas;

1. Convince Celery to let go of the memory earlier. We've tried playing with a bunch of the variables, but none of them have made a noticeable difference and we're finding the documents confusing.
2. We have one task in particular that requires loading a bunch of large components in order to run. However, these components appear to load a new copy for each task (thus filling the memory quickly). Is there a way to get the tasks to access a shared version somewhere? If there is, will this greatly slow down celery?

We're open to other ideas too. We'd just like to find ways to prevent this from happening (even if it doesn't seem to actually be causing any site issues).